# OnClick and OnLoad jQuery script

Tags: jquery

How to run a jQuery script onLoad and onClick please?

Actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gi-repeat').click();
    $(".gi-repeat").click(function(){
        $("#content").eq(0).load("assets/load/content.php");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to trigger click event, so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gi-repeat").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("assets/load/content.php");
    }).click();
});
```

FYI, as IDs must be unique on document context `.eq(0)` doesn't make any sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Just make some changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*$('.gi-repeat').click();*/ // wrong line, cause you're invoking 
                                 // click before initiate
    $(".gi-repeat").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("assets/load/content.php");
    }).click(); // This is a initial trigger to click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can call the function separately onLoad

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gi-repeat").click(giRepeat);
    giRepeat();
 });


 giRepeat = function(){
    $("#content").load("assets/load/content.php");
   }
```